# How to connect H2 database in pentaho

Tags: spring-boot, h2, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

H2 is hosted in an embedded spring application and saved in a file
url: jdbc:h2:file:C:\gesdb

The application is running on 8080 port.
I could see the table employee and values in the table through browser console.

While trying to establish the connection in pentaho error occurs "Connection is broken : unexpected status 1213486160 [90067-214]"

Pentaho connection details

Database Name -> Absolute file path

Port number -> 8080

Have tried FILE_LOCK=NO;
still no luck,
Could not figure out the root cause of the error.

Comment: You cannot use web port of your application as port of database server. If you want to connect to your database in that way, you need to start TCP server of H2 inside your application and connect to its port instead.

Answer (score 1):

By default you can't do multiple connection to h2 db.
Even if you add `;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE` to url link, it depends on version